# Controlling browser window (top window and not popup) height and width from that window itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Controlling browser window (top window and not popup) height and width from that window itself. I am trying to achieve this but no success till now. How I can achieve this?
Till now I tried using

window.resizeTo(weidth , height)

but it works only with child windows and not on top window.
Also I have to control address bar, menu bar etc for top window. Basically all thinks which we can control though JavaScript while opening popup, I want to do it though same window and that window is top window (not a child window).

**In Short** I can’t use this below code for opening popup window.

```
var showMyPage = function(){
   url = "myPage.html";
   window.open(url, "myWindow",
             "toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=400,height=600")
}
```

And I want to achieve same result as of opening popup on clicking below link. So it is obvious that I have to control all options from myPage.html window only.

```
<a href="myPage.html" target="_blank">Open myPage</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out one way to solve this by adding JavaScript code directly on link click and open new window.

```
<a href="myPage.html" target="_blank"
       onclick="window.open(this.href,'myWindow',
                                   'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=400,height=600');
```

but still if you have any other way to solve this then please let me know.